# How to get list of hidden files start with dot (.) .name

Tags: java, android, file, hidden

I making an app and need to find and access to hidden files. The files names start with a dot (.).Ex: in internal storage, I have a folder containing 3 hidden files. But when I get a list of folder files, return nothing. I use this code for getting the list of files

```
File root =android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File Dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/DCIM/Camera");

Dir.listFiles()
```

How I can get the list files that contain hidden files and files hidden by dot name =>.Name

FileManager apps have an option to unhide files. If enable it you can see any hidden file in any directory, I need that

Thanks.

Comment: i use Android Studio ♥

Comment: File[] files = Dir.listFiles(); it should have listed all files if your paths are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files starting with "." are hidden by convention, not by the file system itself. If those files exist then your code should already be listing them.

Those FileManager apps generally behave like your operating system would and hide files starting with "." because users expect them to be hidden, it is not a behavior that is caused by the `File` api.

Comment: Tnx for Your Answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no hidden file in android (or *nix) file system. The '.' is just a convention for tools to not show it and has has nothing to do with the file system.

Your code should work, maybe you do not have any files starting with '.' or try code below, I added a few lines to your code.

```
    File root =android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File Dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/DCIM/Camera/");

    File files[] = Dir.listFiles();

    for(File f: files) {
        if(f.getName().startsWith(".")) {
            Log.e("", "Found: " + f.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tnx i find mistake